# Lualatex not found

Tags: luatex, mactex, pandoc

When I run

```
pandoc markdown.md --template=my-template.tex --latex-engine=lualatex -o test.pdf
```

I get the following error message:

```
pandoc: lualatex not found. lualatex is needed for pdf output.
```

I was running this command a few weeks ago but it not longer works.

Comment: What does `which lualatex` say?

Comment: it says not found. should I just reinstall mactex again

Comment: I'm not sure how you could've borked it unless you've been messing with your `PATH` (which you should really only do when you already know how to fix these sorts of problems) -- what does `which tex` say?

Comment: that says `tex not found` also. My $PATH looks okay:`/Users/xxx/.composer/vendor/bin:/Documents/Ruby:/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/xxx/.rbenv/bin:/Users/xxx/rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/xxx/.yadr/bin:/Users/xxx/.yadr/bin/yadr
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an older installation of MacTeX, make sure `/usr/texbin` is included in your `PATH` environment variable.  Otherwise, use `/Library/TeX/bin`.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you please tell me where to put /usr/texbin  ?
PS: I am using this template http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv

Comment: The document you are compiling is of no consequence. What do you mean 'where do I put it'? See also my recent edit.

Comment: @SeanAllred The change in path is independent of El Capitan, it was just precipitated by changes in El Capitan. With MacTeX 2015 `/Library/TeX/bin` will work on any version of the OS.

Comment: @AlanMunn Good to know, thanks – and edited :-) I've still not updated – I'm afraid (perhaps irrationally) that too many things will break.

Comment: @Günal Sorry, I forgot to ping you. See my comment above.

Comment: @SeanAllred I do not know how to change the path environment. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac